# Android notifications when app isn't in background

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

I'm having this weird issue with notifications in Android. I'm creating notifications this way:

```
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("data", value);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification updateComplete = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notifications)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(100, updateComplete);
```

When the app is running (or in teh background) and hte user clicks on the notification, everything works. `onNewIntent` is called and the data is in the extras. But when the app is not running or in the background, then `onNewIntent()` is NOT called. I tried to get the `intent` from `onCreate()` using `getIntent()`, but it never has extras. Is there anyway to get the extras when the app is not already running?

My activities are all `singleTop`.

Answer (score 0):

Try set some Action on intent:

```
notificationIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Then get Extras in onCreate.

You may also try replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` with `0`.